# What is the difference between upper bound and least upper bound?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm looking at definitions 1.7 and 1.8 in Rudin's principles of real analysis. I'm not seeing how upper bound and least upper bound are different by their definitions. There has to be some difference, but I just don't see it.

Let's say your set is $E = (0,1)$ and the ambient set is $S = [0,4]$. 2 is an upper bound, 3 is an upper bound, 4 is an upper bound, and by definition 1.8, 4 is somehow the least upper bound because all other upper bounds are lower than it? Something isn't adding up here. I would think the *least* upper bound is 1, but somehow it's not? Very confused here. You can explain it as colloquially as you intend, but it will never add up until the definition from the book is sensical. I'm on the third edition, maybe it's a typo?

Comment: What is the definition of ambient set?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but it's the set you pretend is the space of all that exists. When you refer to sets in math, do you notice how you don't always automatically start with the universal set? You start with some subset of the universal set, you pretend your ambient set is the space of all mathematical objects or numbers there is even though you know there's secretly a "bigger" set with more objects in .

Comment: In your example $\sup(E)=1$ because among all the upper bounds for $E$ in $S$, such as $3.2, \pi, \sqrt{2},101/100,1,\dots$ it is the least, i.e. the smallest.

Comment: Your intuition is spot on, this is exactly what I would think intuitively too, but again, this seems to be false according to Rudin's definition. I'm starting to think Rudin's definition is just flat our wrong, that it's missing crucial information.

Comment: You should add definitions in your post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wikipedia's definition here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Formal_definition addresses the ambiguities that preclude a logical understanding that follows directly from Rudin's definition. Wikipedia's definition specifies the intuitive thought several commenters had, that, $b$ is the least upper bound if for the set of all upper bounds $\{z\}$ of a subset $S$ that $b \leq z$ for all $z \in \{z\}.$ This is what I hoped someone would illuminate from Rudin's definition, but alas their definition appears incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Let's quote Definition 1.7 and 1.8 of Rudin.

> **Definition 1.7.** Suppose $S$ is an ordered set, and $E \subseteq S$. If there exists a $\beta \in S$ such that $x \leq \beta$ for every $x \in E$, we say that $E$ is *bounded above*, and call $\beta$ and *upper bound* of $E$.

> **Definition 1.8.** Suppose $S$ is an ordered set, $E \subseteq S$, and $E$ is bounded above. Suppose there exists an $\alpha \in S$ with the following properties:
>
> 1. $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $E$.
> 2. If $\gamma < \alpha$ then $\gamma$ is not an upper bound of $E$.
>
> Then $\alpha$ is called the *least upper bound* of $E$.

I suspect you mix up the inequality sign somewhere, but let's verify which of $1$ or $4$ is the least upper bound.

$4$ is indeed an upper bound of $E$, as $x \leq 4$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. However, it fails criterion (2) - that is, there exists a $\gamma < \alpha$ such that $\gamma$ is an upper bound of $E$. One possible value of $\gamma$ is $1$.

$1$ is also an upper bound of $E$. (2) is also satisfied for $\alpha = 1$, and $4$ doesn't violate the condition as if $\gamma = 4$, then $\gamma \not< \alpha$ ($4 \not< 1$).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134310/discussion-on-answer-by-clement-yung-what-is-the-difference-between-upper-bound).

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right, but got one thing backwards.  In the set $[0,1] \subset [0,4]$, you are right that $1, 2, 3,$ and $4$ are all upper bounds.
But $4$ is the *greatest* upper bound, not the *least* upper bound.
Out of all the upper bounds, $1$ is the smallest, the least, so it is the least upper bound.

Comment: Again that's completely intuitive, but does not follow from Rudin's definition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some elaboration on the subject.

Consider a subset $X\subset\mathbb{R}$ which is not empty and bounded above.

Then there exists a real number, which we are going to call the least upper bound, such that it is an upper bound for $X$ and it is the minimum real number having this property.

But how do I know such value exists? In order to prove its existence, we shall need the continuity axiom which states:

**Axiom of continuity**

Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $Y\subset\mathbb{R}$ be two subsets of the real line. If the relation $x\leq y$ holds for every $x\in X$ and every $y\in Y$, then there exists a real number $c$ such that $x\leq c\leq y$ for every possible values of $x$ and $y$.

**Proof of the existence of the least upper bound**

Consider a set $X\subset\mathbb{R}$ which is not empty and bounded above, where $Y$ is the set of all its upper bounds. Then no matter which pair of values $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ one chooses we have that $x\leq y$.

Consequently, due to the axiom of continuity, we conclude there exists a real number $c$ such that $x\leq c\leq y$ for every $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$. Due to this relation, we deduce that $c$ is an upper bound for $X$ and it is the minimum number having this property, and we are done.

**Proof of uniqueness**

Suppose there are two least upper bounds $s_{1}$ and $s_{2}$ of some nonempty and bounded above set $X\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Since $s_{2}$ is an upper bound, it can be concluded that $s_{2}\geq s_{1}$. Similar consideration leads to the conclusion that $s_{1}\geq s_{2}$. Hence $s_{1} = s_{2}$, just as desired.

**Answer**

Answering your question, an upper bound for some nonempty and bounded above subset $X\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a real number which is greater than or equal to all the elements of such set. The least upper bound is the minimum real number satisfying this relation.